# Long Path Issue with SonarCube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

When we analyse a project with source code in P:\DEVBr\Proj\ folder sonar analysis creates .sonarcube folder like  ".sonarcube\bacman_dev_bacman_dev_long32characterguid\App_Themes\Default\Css\jquery.css". Here path becomes so long that OS crashes to handle the case, Is there any way to configure sonar not to use GUID while generating path names in temporary analysis files ?

Comment: I cut paste folder with long path to D:\ root and thus able to delete. After that used very short code (2char) for project key and name. This had solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Sonar issue, we can't have very long folder names in operating system. We've to fix `file paths` to shorter names. We've modified our code to reduce length of `file path` and restricted `too much folder-file nesting`.